# The calculation of this definite integral

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

What's the integral of $ye^{-y}$?

$\int_0^4e^{-y}\cdot ydy=-5e^{-4}+1$

Comment: Well, the definite integral is a number... and the derivative of a constant is...

Comment: Thank you. I want to know the calculation, not the derivative of the result. The problem has been modified.

Comment: Anything wrong with integration by parts?

Comment: The derivative of something is $e^{-y}\cdot y$?

Comment: Yes; the derivative of infinitely many things is $ye^{-y}$. That dot is just a product.

Comment: I want to know which one fits the question

Comment: They all do; any antiderivative will help you calculate the integral, and any two antiderivatives differ by a constant. Now, if your real question is "Please do my homework for me!", then at least be open and clear about it. You can do this by integration by parts, as I indicated. Did you even bother to try, or were you hoping not to have to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find that definite integral, I would first find the antiderivative of $xe^{-x}$ and once I have it, do the definite integral. I'm going to use $x$ instead of $y$. Use the u-substitution $u=-x$ and then integrate it by parts:

$$
\int x e^{-x}\,dx=\int -x e^{-x}(-x)'\,dx=
\int u e^u\,du=\int u (e^u)'\,du=\\
u e^u-\int u'e^u\,du=u e^u-\int e^u\,du=u e^u-e^u+C=\\
-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+C=-e^{-x}(x+1)+C.
$$

Now that you know what the antiderivative of $xe^{-x}$ is, evaluating the definite integral $\int_{0}^{4}xe^{-x}\,dx$ is going to be trivial. Will you now be able to complete the problem on your own?

Comment: You can also do definite integration by parts; one does not need to do an indefinite integral first.

Comment: Thank you. That's correct. I edited the post.

Comment: Your answer solved my question

Comment: Don't confuse differentiation and integration. In your question, you're asking for the integral of $ye^{-y}$. Not the derivative of it.

Comment: Thank you.It was my error. I edited the post.